# Move or Copy Files within subfolders to another folder

Tags: scripting, cmd, command-line-interface, robocopy

I've been searching around for quite some time but nothing I've found seems to work for me.

I would really like to move the files to another folder on the same drive if possible just in-case the drive happens to be low on space. but none of the move scripts i found seemed to work for me.

i've tried using move, move-items, copy, xcopy, and even robocopy.

robocopy is the only one to work for me so far even tho its creating a new file, it also creates a subfolder that the file is in. in the new location.

so this how my work looks so far

```
D:\DVDBD-Projects\Project1\
                       Movie1\
                       Movie2\
                       Movie3\
```

there is a .mkv file in each movie folder and I would like to move the .mkv in each folder under projects to a new location without creating the folder it was originally in.

So the .mkv files will be moved to D:\DVDBD-Projects\Complete without any folders just mkv files.

This is my code

```
robocopy "D:\DVDBD-Projects\Project1" "D:\DVDBD-Projects\Complete" *.mkv /s
```

this will copy the files to the new location but also create the movie1 folder and so on. if i dont use the /s switch it wont look inside the subfolders and copy the files.

So i was hoping you guys could help me out, is there a way that i can copy or move just the .mkv files to the complete folder.

i plan on adding this code to script that encodes the movies from my camera so it saves me alot of point and clicking and cutting and pasting.

*note - looks like i can use this code

```
pushd "D:\DVDBD-Projects\Project1"
   for /r %%a in (*.mkv) do (
       MOVE "%%a" "D:\DVDBD-Projects\Complete\%%~nxa"
   )
popd
```

this will take all files from subfolders and move them to the destination folder

i could probably also install xxcopy which extends xcopy which would allow me to copy the files from sub directories without creating new folders in the destination

Answer (score 0):

```
for /f "delims=|" %%s in ('dir /ad/b') do robocopy "\\source\%%s\"     "destination\" *.mkv /s
```